# Rails Test - How to test specific validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Using default Rails test suite, how would I write tests that test certain validations only? For example, if I have validations for presence, numeric, and my own validator, how do I just test numeric?

Say I don't have numeric validation working, so this test should fail:

```
test "should test numeric validator" do
    post = Post.new(:number => 'not a number')
    assert !post.save, "it saved a non-numeric value for :number"
end
```

But it'll pass because my own validator didn't allow it to save for some other reason, so my test doesn't really test properly.

Answer (score 4):

You coud assert the `post.errors` hash for the specific field, i.e.:

```
assert_nil post.errors[:number], "it saved a non numeric value for :number"
```